# Web scraping with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, web, web-scraping

Welcome, all

I would like to create a small web application, which needs to scrape data from another website and save the results to a database.

So, currently, I have Laravel 8 installed on my local windows machine, and I made a connection to the database, where I have "items" in the table that I need to save the data in

And the data may be changed from another website so I need this change in the database as well,
and need to **scrape** many items from another website so I need to know id or something else to distinguish one item from another

Now, the question is, what is the best way to do this? I've tried some tutorials but I haven't.

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to approach pretty much every problem.   Rather than ask for approaches, try an approach and ask about specific problems that occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a package Goutte or domcrawler, first you need to do a request of a url for that you can use [GuzzleHttp](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) or get the portion of html content and filter it and then save all this data on a table of your database.
You can read more information about those libraries.
Another library that is more customizable is domcrawler [Dom_Crawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html),
[Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte)